# How do I cross compile the avahi-client and avahi-common libraries?

Tags: c++, c, avahi, cmake

I have developed a C application that uses the [avahi-client](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/tree/master/avahi-client) and [avahi-common](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/tree/master/avahi-common) libraries.

I need to crosscompile these libraries, so I downloaded the source code to do that, but I am not able to find the ./configure file and I dont know how generate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I can not find the ./configure file

You are supposed to generate `./configure` from `configure.ac`:

> ```
> # -*- Autoconf -*-
> # Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
> ```

Source [configure.ac](https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/master/configure.ac)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, i ran the autconf command, and a i got the following error message:

`configure.ac:26: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`

so i had edit the line of the configure.ac where `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` to `m4_pattern_allow(AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE)` 

and i runed again autoconf command and the configure file had been generate succefull.